# How to stop Lua object constructors from sharing nested tables between instances?

Tags: object, constructor, lua

Can anyone fix my buggy Lua object system?

- Different instances have different numeric fields
- **But**  ..  when I add tables to my initialization fields, then those tables are shared between different instances (see example, below).

What I think is that I need to do a deep copy on initial fields but I can't see where. My code is below. Any suggestions?

```lua
Object = {}

function Object:new (o)
  -- o = deep_copy(o) or {} -- <== this didn't work
  -- self = deep copy(self) -- <== this didn't work
  o = o or {}  
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  self.__tostring = show
  return o
end

Account = Object:new{balance = 0,all={}}

function Account:push(v)
  self.all[#self.all+1] = v
end

function Account:deposit(v)
  self.balance = self.balance + v end

function Account:withdraw (v)
  if v > self.balance then
    error"insufficient funds" end
  self.balance = self.balance - v
end

function show(i,  str,sep)
  str,sep = "{",""
  for k,v in pairs(i) do
    if type(v) ~= "function" then
      str = str..sep..tostring(k)..":"..tostring(v)
      sep = ", "
    end
  end
  return str .. "}"
end
```

Just to illustrate the problem, below I have two instances `a` and `b`

When I update `a,b`'s numeric fields, then different instances get different values.

But when I update the `all` table in one instance `a`, it changes it in the other instance `b`.

```lua
a=Account:new()
b=Account:new()
a:deposit(100)
b:deposit(200)
b:push(10)
b:push(20)
a:push(300)

print("a all", show(a), show(a.all))
print("b all", show(b), show(b.all))
```

The output should be:

```
a all   {balance:100}   {3:300}
b all   {balance:200}   {1:10, 2:20}
```

But what actually comes out is:

```
a all   {balance:100}   {1:10, 2:20, 3:300}
b all   {balance:200}   {1:10, 2:20, 3:300}
```

Comment: `o = deep_copy(o) or {}` looks about like what you needed. What "didn't work" about it?

Comment: yeah, that's the puzzle. at

https://gist.github.com/timm/59dff9d191f2ea8318578f7f27dd064d#file-object-lua-L15

I make the change you suggest. but the bug persists (where writing to lists inside one instance effects the other). So I checked my `deep copy` function, ran some tests, and that parts seems to be working correctly (nested lists are copied). Which means the puzzle remains....

Comment: I'm asking you: when you tried it that way, what happened and what did you observe that led you to conclude that it "didn't work"?

Comment: thanks for asking. see the bug.md file at https://gist.github.com/timm/59dff9d191f2ea8318578f7f27dd064d#file-bug-md

Comment: Please don't edit comments in ways that significantly change their meaning after someone else has replied to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to inherit from Object, easiest is to create a new constructor for account as well. This should set a balance and and all for each object, not on the class itself.

```
Object = {}
Account = {}

function Object:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    self.__tostring = show
    return o
end

function Account:new(o)
    o = o or Object:new(o)
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    o.balance = 0
    o.all = {}
    return o
end

a all   {all:table: 0x55ab93ec70d0, balance:100}        {1:300}
b all   {all:table: 0x55ab93ec6ed0, balance:200}        {1:10, 2:20}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do `self.__index = self`, and your prototype has an `all` field, but you never set one in the objects that you create. As a result, accesses to it (as `push` does) will always go through `__index` and end up hitting the prototype.

Comment: thanks for your work on this. if I comment out  `-- self.__index = self` then that leads to the error `attempt to call a nil value (method 'new')`. So that line is needed to join back to the class name.

Comment: My point wasn't that you don't need that; it's that each object needs its own `all`.

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph said, you need to create distinct `all` for every object.
You could either write function `Account:new()` or write `Object:new()` function which accepts initializer (so that you would not need to implement distinct `:new()` for every class):

```
Object = {__init = function(o) end}

function Object:new(o, init)
  -- when creating an instance:
  --  o: the object itself
  -- when creating a class:
  --  o:    table containing shared fields and methods
  --  init: initializer for instances of this class
  o = o or {}
  self.__init(o)
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  if init then
    function o.__init(o)
      self.__init(o)
      init(o)
    end
  end
  return o
end

Account = Object:new({}, function(o) o.all={}; o.balance=0; end)

function Account:push(v)
  self.all[#self.all+1] = v
end

function Account:deposit(v)
  self.balance = self.balance + v
end

function Account:withdraw (v)
  if v > self.balance then
    error"insufficient funds" end
  self.balance = self.balance - v
end


function show(i,  str,sep)
  str,sep = "{",""
  for k,v in pairs(i) do
    if type(v) ~= "function" then
      str = str..sep..tostring(k)..":"..tostring(v)
      sep = ", "
    end
  end
  return str .. "}"
end

Object.__tostring = show


a=Account:new()
b=Account:new()
a:deposit(100)
b:deposit(200)
b:push(10)
b:push(20)
a:push(300)

print("a all", show(a), show(a.all))
print("b all", show(b), show(b.all))
```